# Context scoping using the Rally RPM

Tags: javascript, sdk, rally

Recently, I created a RPM treepanel, using the Rally SDK 2.0, which allows the user to select several portfolio items from the tree. What I would like to do is use a WsapiDataStore call to pull all the User Stories which are scoped below the selected RPM level(s). When I was using a project selector, this was as easy as setting the context attribute in the call like so:

```
context: {
    project: '/project/' + projectObjectID;
}
```

If I do this using the RPM project IDs it doesn't seem to function in the same way. Is there a way for me to specify a context using RPM project nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a context scoping that will accomplish this - right now the only way to query the relationship would be to recursively walk the child "tree" of a particular Artifact.

Lookback API will make this much easier, by making it possible to grab the entire hierarchy of parent/child objects with a single query - see the answer to this question:

[Lookback API: Find all leaf node stories under a known parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725244/lookback-api-find-all-leaf-node-stories-under-a-known-parent)

Comment: I was actually starting to write code to do a traversal and the whole time I'm just thinking "there has got to be a better way". Good to know there is! I am really enjoying the Lookback API (especially coming from the old way it was done) but one gripe I have is the inability to test my apps with the debug page when the incorporate it. Do you know if there's plans to add this functionality any time soon? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: As of today, it appears as though the Lookback API is working from the debug page. Thank you! :)