# WSAPI: Finding the root parent of a story

Tags: rally

I have a WSAPI query that returns a number of stories.  For each of these stories, I'd like to inspect the "root" parent.  So I make the query, and in the "fetch" field I request "Parent".

However, this only gives me to the immediate parent.  If the parent has a parent, that does not seem to be returned.  In contrast, if I request a story's children, I can go down many levels.

Is there a way with the WSAPI to do a single query of user stories so that I can get to the root parent of each?  And in fact, sometimes the parent is a Feature level portfolio item, so ideally that needs to be included as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only possible to traverse one level of the hierarchy at a time in a WSAPI request.  You'll have to continue loading each parent until you reach the top.

Comment: So if the query leaves the "Parent" field blank, I can tell it has a parent using the "HasParent" field.  But how do I query for the parent?  Apparently I cant use (Children.FormattedID = "X") since I can't query on the "Children" field, so without the ID of the parent, how do I query for it?

Comment: Nevrmind, I get it-- I just query the object directly, asking for the parent

Comment: Is it just an oddity of the WSAPI that it will retrieve the hierarchy of children in a query but not the parents?

Comment: You could call it an oddity. Strictly speaking WSAPI provides a collection of Children, but it only goes "one-deep" meaning that to traverse further down the tree, you have to recursively query in that direction too.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer:

[Lookback API: Find all leaf node stories under a known parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725244/lookback-api-find-all-leaf-node-stories-under-a-known-parent)

Lookback API makes it possible to grab the entire hierarchy of parent/child objects with a single query. LBAPI is currently in a limited public preview for a subset of Rally subscriptions, but the goal is to make a full public preview available soon.

Comment: Exactly, to get the "root" item, you would inspect the _ItemHierarchy. You can actually just return the root using the $slice operator in the fields specification. `find={FormattedID:"S35244",__At:"current"}&fields={_ItemHierarchy:{$slice:1}}` will just return the the root item. Note, that this will crawl all the way up the ItemHierarchy even into Portfolio Items.